# firebase transaction dynamic key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JSON and I'm trying to add a transaction to "count" on the account of a logged in user, however firebase ads the dynamic key and I'm having trouble with the firebase reference in that regard.

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-KRPSyO4B48IpBnHBTYg" : {
      "count" : "100",
      "email" : "",
      "userId" : ""
    }
  },
  "products" : {
    "-KUKRafaNurpFhGF4jQa" : {
      "name" : ""
    }
  },
}
```

I was trying to make this work:

```
firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + accounts.id+'/count').transaction(function(value) {
  if (value) {
    value++;
  }
 return value;
});
```

which is all good aside from the fact that I do not know what the "accounts.id" is even when the user is logged in.

What is the correct way to update the count record of a logged in user?

Comment: What is the data under `/accounts` meant to be? If it's a list of users, you should store them under their UID instead of a push ID.

Comment: I see, the userId also has a dynamic key, definitely a better approach.  That data is indeed the user accounts.

Comment: OK. In that case: store the users under their UID. If you need to use push IDs, you will need to write a query to determine the push IDs that contain the UID you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the logged in user details by:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
    userId = user.uid
} else {
    // No user is signed in.
}
```

once you have the user ID your code should work